# Neo4j - Path count performances

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, database-performance

I'm working with Neo4j 2.1.7. I'm trying to count the paths starting from a node and terminating to the same node (i.e. loops), with maximum given path length.

My (very simple) query is

```
match p=(n:MyLabel) -[r*..maxLength]- (n)
return n.myid, count(p)
```

The entire graph has 200k nodes, while MyLabel nodes are only 50k, but I'm having very poor performance even with low values of maxLength (5 or 6).

How can I improve?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a global graph query, which will create exponential results.

E.g. if you have 100 rels per node, then 6 steps out will be 100^6 = 1.000.000.000.000 paths that it will find *per node* and then you also go over all nodes.

I recommend that you instead look at shortestPath, but even so, doing that 50k times is still a lot, try to use `PROFILE` to output the query plan so you see the amount of data you touch.

```
match (n:MyLabel)
match shortestPath((n)-[*..maxLength]- (n))
return n.myid, count(*)
```

It might be that Neo4j 2.2 with the new query planner is better at that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I don't understand the shortestPath function: your query produces 0 results, while removing shortestPath (and using the global graph operation) produces various results. Can you point me to some documentation? Thanks a lot